# Why doesn't adding CORS headers to an OPTIONS route allow browsers to access my API?

Tags: node.js, express, coffeescript, cors

I am trying to support CORS in my Node.js application that uses the Express.js web framework. I have read [a Google group discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/express-js/browse_thread/thread/71db58df2c74d06a) about how to handle this, and read a few articles about how CORS works. First, I did this (code is written in CoffeeScript syntax):

```
app.options "*", (req, res) ->
  res.header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'
  res.header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true
  # try: 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS'
  res.header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, OPTIONS'
  # try: 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept'
  res.header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type'
  # ...
```

It doesn't seem to work. It seems like my browser (Chrome) is not sending the initial OPTIONS request. When I just updated the block for the resource I need to submit a cross-origin GET request to:

```
app.get "/somethingelse", (req, res) ->
  # ...
  res.header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'
  res.header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true
  res.header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS'
  res.header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type'
  # ...
```

It works (in Chrome). This also works in Safari.

I have read that...

> In a browser implementing CORS, each cross-origin GET or POST request is preceded by an OPTIONS request that checks whether the GET or POST is OK.

So my main question is, how come this doesn't seem to happen in my case? Why isn't my app.options block called? Why do I need to set the headers in my main app.get block?

Comment: This answer maybe useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58064366/7059557

Comment: Did you declare **app.options('*', cors());** before all routes?

Answer (score 221, accepted):

To answer your main question, the CORS spec only requires the OPTIONS call to precede the POST or GET if the POST or GET has any non-simple content or headers in it.

Content-Types that require a CORS pre-flight request (the OPTIONS call) are any Content-Type *except the following*:

1. `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
2. `multipart/form-data`
3. `text/plain`

Any other Content-Types apart from those listed above will trigger a pre-flight request.

As for Headers, any Request Headers *apart from the following* will trigger a pre-flight request:

1. `Accept`
2. `Accept-Language`
3. `Content-Language`
4. `Content-Type`
5. `DPR`
6. `Save-Data`
7. `Viewport-Width`
8. `Width`

Any other Request Headers will trigger the pre-flight request.

So, you could add a custom header such as: `x-Trigger: CORS`, and that should trigger the pre-flight request and hit the OPTIONS block.

See [MDN Web API Reference - CORS Preflighted requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests)

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: The page I linked to seems to have a number of examples.  Could you tell me what example you think is missing?

Comment: In general though, link-only answers are fragile because they could, at any moment, be broken. That said, this answer seems good enough in that it's highlighting the general conditions under which `OPTIONS` blocks don't send. Would be nice if it had the list of accepted `HEADERS`, or which `content-types` require `OPTIONS`, etc but it's a good start

Comment: Great answer thank you, but adding a custom x-Trigger header only to trigger the pre-flight sounds odd to me, is that suggested only for "educational" purposes here or it's something actually useful?

Answer (score 728):

I found the easiest way is to use the node.js package [cors](https://npmjs.org/package/cors). The simplest usage is:

```
var cors = require('cors')

var app = express()
app.use(cors())
```

There are, of course many ways to configure the behaviour to your needs; the page linked above shows a number of examples.

Comment: It fails for me when I use it with credentials. :( Everything else worked like a charm.. But its of no use to me if it fails withCredentials set to true

Comment: Its working fine for ajax request. I want CORS implementation for Script Tags and iFrame because in these requests the Origin is not present in the request header :( How to implement this ?

Comment: You need to also set `cors({credentials: true, origin: true})`

Comment: how do you enable options preflight here?

Comment: @nlawson Never, ever use `cors({credentials: true, origin: true})`! It amounts to voiding the same-origin policy. Very insecure.

Comment: @Arnout Engelen I have a public fetch API. But some people were telling to enable CORS as it blocks their requests. I know there is an npm package called cors. 
But I saw that many Public APIs do not have CORS enabled. I also read some articles about the security risks in CORS.

**I was asking that will it be wrong to enable CORS**. Few people are calling the API from client-side code that is running in the browsers.
Any suggestion is gratefully accepted.

Comment: @DronBhattacharya the question you are responding to is about *how* to enable CORS. Your question is about *in which cases* it is OK to enable CORS. I think that is indeed a good and interesting one, but is too 'big' to try to answer in the comments here - it should be a separate question.

Comment: @ArnoutEngelen Please answer these: [q 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71250046/what-is-secure-configuration-for-cors-used-in-express-js-api-without-compromisin) and [q 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71247652/how-to-set-cors-header-on-my-api-server-to-allow-requests-from-localhost). They are related to the above comment. If the questions are not clear, help improving them

Answer (score 477):

Try passing control to the next matching route.  If Express is matching app.get route first, then it won't continue onto the options route unless you do this *(note use of next)*:

```js
app.get('somethingelse', (req, res, next) => {
  //..set headers etc.
        
  next();
});
```

In terms of organising the CORS stuff, I put it in a middleware which is working well for me:

```js
// CORS middleware
const allowCrossDomain = (req, res, next) => {
  res.header(`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, `example.com`);
  res.header(`Access-Control-Allow-Methods`, `GET,PUT,POST,DELETE`);
  res.header(`Access-Control-Allow-Headers`, `Content-Type`);
  next();
};

//...

app.configure(() => {
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({ secret: `cool beans` }));
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  // CORS middleware
  app.use(allowCrossDomain);
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(`public`));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this approach. Looks cleaner than having to add the setting of the headers in each of my resource. But I was hoping someone could explain why the preflight request using the OPTIONS method was not performed at all.

Comment: Updated the answer, hope that helps.

Comment: I believe OPTIONS happens before a GET, whereas if you're doing a POST - there is no OPTIONS request...

Comment: Is `config.allowedDomains` a comma-delimited string or an array?

Comment: I realize that `app.use(allowCrossDomain);` must put before `app.use(app.router);`. Could you please explain why? Thanks.

Comment: config.allowedDomains should be a space separated array

Comment: I ended up using something similar. Did anyone notice that the OPTIONS 204 creates an extra session since it doesn't send any cookies?

Comment: The extra session was removed by simply rearranging the express middleware order. On another note, this needs a little more security. if the origin is not in the allowed domain then the request is still processed, only the browser won't be able to see it plus the origin can be spoofed. My advice would be to do a check and if the origin is not in the allowed list then return 403 immediately. Also is any sensitive information is being served, validate the user via a session.

Comment: @mcfedr Could you please explain what do you mean by space separated array?

Comment: @pootzko I realise thats a bit unclear, it should be a string, with spaces, eg, `"example.com test.com anotherdomain.com"`

Comment: @mcfedr Thanks for the reply. Although I tried that one out, and it didn't work for me. What did was something like this: "example.com" || "test.com" || "whatever.com". Basically chained or's.

Comment: for debug purposes use 
`res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);` as 
`res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', config.allowedDomains);`

Comment: This worked really well for me, using something like config = { allowedDomains : ["http://allowed.com"] };

Comment: I edited the answer and removed `config.allowedDomains`. As stated by the [CORS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-header), you can have only one domain in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header (or `*` or `null`).

Comment: `app.configure` is deprecated http://expressjs.com/ru/guide/migrating-4.html#other-changes

Comment: you should also set `res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');`

Comment: This doesn't respond to OPTIONS requests for me - i get a 404

Answer (score 134):

To stay in the same idea of routing. I  use this code :

```
app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  next();
});
```

Similar to http://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html example

Comment: This goes in the grunt.js file?

Comment: What about preflight?

Comment: No @OliverDixon, this is on the server side

Answer (score 100):

do

```
npm install cors --save
```

and just add  these lines in your main file where your request going (keep it before any route).

```
const cors = require('cors');
const express = require('express');
let app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());
```

Comment: `app.options('*', cors())` // include before other routes

Answer (score 64):

I have made a more complete middleware suitable for express or connect. It supports `OPTIONS` requests for preflight checking. Note that it will allow CORS access to anything, you might want to put in some checks if you want to limit access.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var oneof = false;
    if(req.headers.origin) {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
        oneof = true;
    }
    if(req.headers['access-control-request-method']) {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', req.headers['access-control-request-method']);
        oneof = true;
    }
    if(req.headers['access-control-request-headers']) {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', req.headers['access-control-request-headers']);
        oneof = true;
    }
    if(oneof) {
        res.header('Access-Control-Max-Age', 60 * 60 * 24 * 365);
    }

    // intercept OPTIONS method
    if (oneof && req.method == 'OPTIONS') {
        res.send(200);
    }
    else {
        next();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey there, I came across your solution and was wondering if the 'oneof' flag should be set false if one of the headers wasn't detected?

Comment: Some requests will not have all the headers.
Specifically a GET request will be sent by the browser, and when it doesn't get a correct allow-origin response an error is given to js.
Whereas for a POST request, the OPTIONS request is first sent, with the allow-method header, and only afterwards, the actual POST request will be sent.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks. Did you ever run into trouble by not putting res.send(200) in there if the req method was 'options'?

Comment: I dont think i have tried sending something else, I would imagine any other response will cause the browser to refuse the request that it is preflighting.

Comment: works like charm, i would just add a list of authorized domains for more security

Comment: @Shide completely agree, you really ought to be checking the origin domain is one you trust

Answer (score 43):

Do something like this:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 40):

install cors module of expressjs. you can follow these steps >

**Installation**

```
npm install cors
```

**Simple Usage (Enable All CORS Requests)**

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
app.use(cors());
```

for more details go to https://github.com/expressjs/cors

Comment: ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined``` The most basic app setup.

Comment: Are you sure you  have request object ? :)

Answer (score 23):

Testing done with express + node + ionic running in differente ports.

`Localhost:8100`

`Localhost:5000`

```
// CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) headers to support Cross-site HTTP requests

app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
       res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
       res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
       res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
       next();
});
```

Comment: In which file do we need to add this lines?

Answer (score 22):

first simply install cors in your project.
Take terminal(command prompt) and `cd` to your project directory and run the below command:

```
npm install cors --save
```

Then take the server.js file and change the code to add the following in it:

```
var cors = require('cors');


var app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'DELETE, PUT, GET, POST');
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
   next();
});
```

This worked for me..

Comment: You don't need `cors` if you're doing the `res.header` stuff. `cors` is a library that handles all that for you. Delete your first & 3rd lines (AKA everything with `cors`) and you'll find that it still works.

Comment: heck i'm pretty sure all you really need is this line `res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");`

Comment: though do keep in mind that you're compromising your security by doing that. :)

Answer (score 12):

Some time ago, I faced this problem so I did this to allow CORS in my nodejs app:

First you **need to install** `cors` by using below command :

```
npm install cors --save
```

Now **add the following code** to your app starting file like ( `app.js or server.js`)

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var cors = require('cors');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//enables cors
app.use(cors({
  'allowedHeaders': ['sessionId', 'Content-Type'],
  'exposedHeaders': ['sessionId'],
  'origin': '*',
  'methods': 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
  'preflightContinue': false
}));

require('./router/index')(app);
```

Comment: tried this after installing cors. Cors is not a function

Answer (score 11):

This works for me, as its an easy implementation inside the routes, im using meanjs and its working fine, safari, chrome, etc.

```
app.route('/footer-contact-form').post(emailer.sendFooterMail).options(function(req,res,next){ 
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); 
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
        return res.send(200);

    });
```

Answer (score 11):

If you want to make it controller specific, you can use:

```
res.setHeader("X-Frame-Options", "ALLOWALL");
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET");
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
```

Please note that this will also allow iframes.

Answer (score 8):

In my `index.js` I added:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
   next();
})
```

Comment: I should comment that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin = *` means that you won't be able to send Cookies to the server, they will be rejected by the CORS Policy - source : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Requests_with_credentials . So, dont use this if you want to use cookies.

Answer (score 8):

`cors` package is recommended way to for solving the CORS policy issue in express.js, but you also need to make sure to enable it for `app.options` as well, like below:

```js
const cors = require('cors');

// enable cors
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: true,
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
    credentials: true,
  })
);
app.options(
  '*',
  cors({
    origin: true,
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
    credentials: true,
  })
);
```

Answer (score 6):

Can refer the code below for the same. Source: [Academind/node-restful-api](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL55RiY5tL51q4D-B63KBnygU6opNPFk_q)

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

//acts as a middleware
//to handle CORS Errors
app.use((req, res, next) => { //doesn't send response just adjusts it
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*") //* to give access to any origin
    res.header(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization" //to give access to all the headers provided
    );
    if(req.method === 'OPTIONS'){
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, GET'); //to give access to all the methods provided
        return res.status(200).json({});
    }
    next(); //so that other routes can take over
})
```

Comment: I saw many answer and this have something which is importan, I tried to use this part of the code after some other configurations and it didn't work and for some reason, I tried putting the code after app `const app = express();` and works! I think is important to mention it.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest answer is to just use the [cors package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors).

```
const cors = require('cors');

const app = require('express')();
app.use(cors());
```

That will enable CORS across the board. If you want to learn how to [enable CORS without outside modules](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/cors#setting-up-cors-support), all you really need is some [Express middleware](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/express/middleware) that sets the ['Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin). That's the minimum you need to allow cross-request domains from a browser to your server.

```
app.options('*', (req, res) => {
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.send('ok');
});

app.use((req, res) => {
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

My simplest solution with Express 4.2.0 (EDIT: Doesn't seem to work in 4.3.0) was:

```
function supportCrossOriginScript(req, res, next) {
    res.status(200);
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");

    // res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin");
    // res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    // res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","POST, OPTIONS");
    // res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT, HEAD");
    // res.header("Access-Control-Max-Age","1728000");
    next();
}

// Support CORS
app.options('/result', supportCrossOriginScript);

app.post('/result', supportCrossOriginScript, function(req, res) {
    res.send('received');
    // do stuff with req
});
```

I suppose doing `app.all('/result', ...)` would work too...

Answer (score 4):

Below worked for me, hope it helps someone!

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
let app = express();

app.use(cors({ origin: true }));
```

Got reference from https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html#configuring-cors

Comment: What file does that go in?  peanutbutter.js?

Comment: not sure about peanutbutter.js, for me it is express.js.
basically, it should be the file where you require your express app, initialize it, 
and require route files.

Answer (score 3):

Try this in your main js file:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header(
  "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
  "Authorization, X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Request-Method"
);
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
res.header("Allow", "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
next();
});
```

This should solve your problem

Answer (score 3):

using `CORS` package. and put this parameters:

```
cors({credentials: true, origin: true, exposedHeaders: '*'})
```

Comment: The exact answer I was looking to allow my `auth-token` header to be visible in response header

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get CORS working without the **cors** NPM package (for the pure joy of learning!), you can definitely handle OPTIONS calls yourself. Here's what worked for me:

```
app.options('*', (req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200, '', {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS',
    }).end();
});
```

Nice and simple, right? Notice the use of **res.writeHead()** instead of res.header(), which I am unfamiliar with.

Answer (score 2):

In typescript, if you want to use the node.js package [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

```
/**
* app.ts
* If you use the cors library
*/

import * as express from "express";
[...]
import * as cors from 'cors';

class App {
   public express: express.Application;

   constructor() {
       this.express = express();
       [..]
       this.handleCORSErrors();
   }

   private handleCORSErrors(): any {
       const corsOptions: cors.CorsOptions = {
           origin: 'http://example.com',
           optionsSuccessStatus: 200
       };
       this.express.use(cors(corsOptions));
   }
}

export default new App().express;
```

If you don't want to use third part libraries for cors error handling, you need to change the handleCORSErrors() method.

```
/**
* app.ts
* If you do not use the cors library
*/

import * as express from "express";
[...]

class App {
   public express: express.Application;

   constructor() {
       this.express = express();
       [..]
       this.handleCORSErrors();
   }

   private handleCORSErrors(): any {
       this.express.use((req, res, next) => {
           res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
           res.header(
               "Access-Control-ALlow-Headers",
               "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
           );
           if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
               res.header(
                   "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                   "PUT, POST, PATCH, GET, DELETE"
               );
               return res.status(200).json({});
           } 
           next(); // send the request to the next middleware
       });
    }
}

export default new App().express;
```

For using the app.ts file

```
/**
* server.ts
*/
import * as http from "http";
import app from "./app";

const server: http.Server = http.createServer(app);

const PORT: any = process.env.PORT || 3000;
server.listen(PORT);
```

Comment: "If the server is written in typescript" — It isn't. The question says it is written in CoffeeScript.

Comment: @Quentin I just wanted to show an alternative in typesript, hoping that this could help somebody.

Answer (score 2):

Using Express Middleware works great for me. If you are already using Express, just add the following middleware rules. It should start working.

```
app.all("/api/*", function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Cache-Control, Pragma, Origin, Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST");
  return next();
});

app.all("/api/*", function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.method.toLowerCase() !== "options") {
    return next();
  }
  return res.send(204);
});
```

[Reference](https://williambert.online/2013/06/allow-cors-with-localhost-in-chrome/)

Answer (score 2):

If your Express Server has **Authorization enabled**, you can achieve that like this

```
const express = require('express');
const app=express();
const cors=require("cors");
app.use(cors({
   credentials: true, // for authorization
}));
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I found it to be extremely easy to do this with the npm request package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)

Then I based my solution on this post http://blog.javascripting.com/2015/01/17/dont-hassle-with-cors/

```
'use strict'

const express = require('express');
const request = require('request');

let proxyConfig = {
    url : {
        base: 'http://servertoreach.com?id=',
    }
}

/* setting up and configuring node express server for the application */
let server = express();
server.set('port', 3000);


/* methods forwarded to the servertoreach proxy  */
server.use('/somethingElse', function(req, res)
{
    let url = proxyConfig.url.base + req.query.id;
    req.pipe(request(url)).pipe(res);
});


/* start the server */
server.listen(server.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('express server with a proxy listening on port ' + server.get('port'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is similiar to Pat's answer with the difference that I finish with res.sendStatus(200); instead of next();

The code will catch all the requests of the method type OPTIONS and send back access-control-headers.

```js
app.options('/*', (req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With');
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

The code accepts CORS from all origins as requested in the question. However, it would be better to replace the * with a specific origin i.e. http://localhost:8080 to prevent misuse.

Since we use the app.options-method instead of the app.use-method we don't need to make this check:

```
req.method === 'OPTIONS'
```

which we can see in some of the other answers.

I found the answer here: http://johnzhang.io/options-request-in-express.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is install the cors module in your project using:

```
npm i --save cors
```

Then in your server file import it using the following:

```
import cors from 'cors';
```

Then simply use it as a middleware like this:

```
app.use(cors());
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

simple is hard:

```
 let my_data = []
const promise = new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
    axios.post('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=33.69057660000001,72.9782724&destination=33.691478,%2072.978594&key=AIzaSyApzbs5QDJOnEObdSBN_Cmln5ZWxx323vA'
        , { 'Origin': 'https://localhost:3000' })
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(`axios response ${response.data}`)
            const my_data = response.data
            resolve(my_data)
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error)
            alert('connection error')
        })
})
promise.then(data => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

We can avoid CORS and forward the requests to the other server instead:

```
// config:
var public_folder = __dirname + '/public'
var apiServerHost = 'http://other.server'

// code:
console.log("starting server...");

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var request = require('request');

// serve static files
app.use(express.static(public_folder));

// if not found, serve from another server
app.use(function(req, res) {
    var url = apiServerHost + req.url;
    req.pipe(request(url)).pipe(res);
});

app.listen(80, function(){
    console.log("server ready");
});
```

Comment: this does not answer the question asked

Answer (score 0):

I used the following steps to my web app and I had success:

Add the cors package to the express:

```
npm install cors --save
```

Add following lines **after the bodyParser configuration**. I had some troubles adding before bodyParser:

```
 // enable cors to the server
const corsOpt = {
    origin: process.env.CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN || '*', // this work well to configure origin url in the server
    methods: ['GET', 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'], // to works well with web app, OPTIONS is required
    allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'] // allow json and token in the headers
};
app.use(cors(corsOpt)); // cors for all the routes of the application
app.options('*', cors(corsOpt)); // automatic cors gen for HTTP verbs in all routes, This can be redundant but I kept to be sure that will always work.
```

Answer (score 0):

If i were you @OP i would change my programming paradigm.

assuming you are getting these CORS blocked because you are making requests to localhost or something similar.

Eventually if you are going to deploy to production optoins like `Google Cloud Platform` or `Heroku` or , you will no have to worry about CORS like allow origin or whatever when in production.

so when testing the server just use `postman` and you will not get CORS blocked, after that deploy your server and then work on your client.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Express middleware, block your domain and methods.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", process.env.DOMAIN); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With reactstrap "npm run start" at 3000 and a nodejs express server at 3001 in 2023 the following in the server.js was working before all other routes :

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
    next();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Below code will work ,but first install cors by:

npm install --save cors

Then:

```
module.exports = function(app) { 
var express = require("express");
var cors = require('cors');
var router = express.Router();
app.use(cors());

app.post("/movies",cors(), function(req, res) { 
res.send("test");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

using nodejs without express/external libraries I made use of the below method within my server.js file.    The key parts here are getting the origin from the request header then allowing it in the server response at which point we can set the header that will be returned including the allowed origin if a match is found.

```
    **const origin = req.headers.origin;**

      let decoder = new StringDecoder('utf-8');
      let buffer = '';
      req.on('data', function (data) {
        buffer += decoder.write(data);
      });
      req.on('end', function () {
        buffer += decoder.end();

        let chosenHandler = typeof (server.router[trimmedPath]) !== 'undefined' ? server.router[trimmedPath] : handlers.notFound;

const data = { ....data object vars}

// should be wrapped in try catch block
      chosenHandler(data, function (statusCode, payload, contentType) {
        server.processHandlerResponse(res, method, trimmedPath, statusCode, payload, contentType, **origin**);


server.processHandlerResponse = function (res, method, trimmedPath, statusCode, payload, contentType, origin) {
  contentType = typeof (contentType) == 'string' ? contentType : 'json';

  statusCode = typeof (statusCode) == 'number' ? statusCode : 200;

  let payloadString = '';
  if (contentType == 'json') {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    const allowedOrigins = ['https://www.domain1.com', 'https://someotherdomain','https://yetanotherdomain',
    ...// as many as you need
  ];
    **if (allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) > -1) {
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
    }**
    payload = typeof (payload) == 'object' ? payload : {};
    payloadString = JSON.stringify(payload);
  }

... //  if (other content type) ...rinse and repeat..
```

Answer (score -3):

/*first of all, and this might be the problem amongst junior devs out there, like myself: make sure to use "lambda" >>>> "`" and not "'" in your **fetch** method! */

``` const response = await fetch(`https://api....`);

/*plus, the following article is highly recommended: https://developer.edamam.com/api/faq*/